# How to post mult array data in the db using create fuction in laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

How to add this kind of data in the database using a create method    `ModelName::create()`?
The data are in an array. There is outer array and inner array.

What i want from that array is something like this

```
ModelName::create([
'level' => $this->level,
])
```

In my form I use Livewire component thats why I used $this

I tried to use foreach loop so I can get individual elements but I didn't succeed

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `'level' => serialize($this->level)` your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this question this one works for me

```
foreach ($this->education as $item) {

            EducationBackground::create([
                'personal_id' => $this->personal_id_from_db,
                'level' => $item['level'],
                'program' => $item['program'],
                'institution' => $item['institution'],
                'year_completed' => $item['year_completed'],
            ]);
```